# What does the turtle onscreenclick return in Python? How do I make an area a 'button'?

Tags: python-turtle

Does `turtle.onscreenclick` return the x- & y-coordinates? Also, how do I make a rectangle where if I click within it changes the color of the rectangle?

Comment: It doesn't return anything.  There is nothing meaningful that it could possibly return, because *no click has occurred yet*.  It just specifies a function that will be called if and when there is actually a click.

Comment: Ok but then how do I use it so it returns the x and y coordinates

Comment: You receive the coordinates as the parameters to the function you pass to `onscreenclick()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! You helped.

Answer (score 0):

`turtle.onscreenclick` binds the function in the brackets to the given key.

`turtle.onscreenclick(fun, 1)` where 1 is the left click and 3 is the right click.

Explanation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick